# how to sort a list of key-value stores by a specific key?

Tags: python, sorting

suppose the input is like this:

```
"[{'ability': 18, 'spin': -14, 'strike': 0, 'purity': 5, 'power': 257}, {'ability': -6, 'spin': 147, 'strike': -17, 'purity': 6, 'power': 288}, {'ability': 9, 'spin': 272, 'strike': 10, 'purity': 8, 'power': 256}, {'ability': 0, 'spin': 138, 'strike': -6, 'purity': 19, 'power': 205}]"
```

I have to sort the input based on the values at the key "ability".

```
def sort_kvs(lsts):
      l = len(lsts)
      sort = []
      smallest = lsts[0]["ability"]
      for i in range (l):
        if lsts[i]["ability"] < lsts[0]["ability"]:
          smallest = lsts[i]["ability"]
          small = lsts[i]
          sort.append(small)
      return sort
```

I want the output like this:`[{'ability': -6, 'spin': 147, 'strike': -17, 'purity': 6, 'power': 288}, {'ability': 0, 'spin': 138, 'strike': -6, 'purity': 19, 'power': 205}, {'ability': 9, 'spin': 272, 'strike': 10, 'purity': 8, 'power': 256}, {'ability': 18, 'spin': -14, 'strike': 0, 'purity': 5, 'power': 257}]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` with a custom `key`:

```
>>> l = [{'ability': 18, 'spin': -14, 'strike': 0, 'purity': 5, 'power': 257}, {'ability': -6, 'spin': 147, 'strike': -17, 'purity': 6, 'power': 288}, {'ability': 9, 'spin': 272, 'strike': 10, 'purity': 8, 'power': 256}, {'ability': 0, 'spin': 138, 'strike': -6, 'purity': 19, 'power': 205}]
>>> list(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["ability"]))
[{'ability': -6, 'spin': 147, 'strike': -17, 'purity': 6, 'power': 288}, {'ability': 0, 'spin': 138, 'strike': -6, 'purity': 19, 'power': 205}, {'ability': 9, 'spin': 272, 'strike': 10, 'purity': 8, 'power': 256}, {'ability': 18, 'spin': -14, 'strike': 0, 'purity': 5, 'power': 257}]
```

No need to wrap `sorted` with `list` if it is `python2`

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['ability'])
```

output:

```
{'ability': -6, 'spin': 147, 'strike': -17, 'purity': 6, 'power': 288}
{'ability': 0, 'spin': 138, 'strike': -6, 'purity': 19, 'power': 205}
{'ability': 9, 'spin': 272, 'strike': 10, 'purity': 8, 'power': 256}
{'ability': 18, 'spin': -14, 'strike': 0, 'purity': 5, 'power': 257}
```